# Manifest name attribute of <service> tag

Tags: java, android

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) in manifest element

```
<service android:name=".PrinterService"
```

should be specifried name of the Service subclass. My subclass is named PrinterService and is defined as following

```
package arrowsys.vrp.print;

#import
public class PrinterService extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public class PrinterSession extends PrinterDiscoverySession {
    }
}
```

When I put into attribute name `.PrinterService` I get

> Cannot resolve symbol

With value `.service.PrinterService` I get

> AidleType package expected, got '.'

**Edit:** to make it more simple, I have deleted folder arrowsys.vrp.printer/service so my PrinterService.java is directly in arrowsys.vrp.printer.

Now the package definition is `package arrowsys.vrp.print`;

Complete AndroidManifest.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="arrowsys.vrp.print">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name="arrowsys.vrp.print.PrinterService"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_PRINT_SERVICE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.vrp.print.PrinterService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [App Manifest Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) you have to include the full package path or your service **should be a child of the application package**

> If you define a subclass, as you almost always would for the component classes (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, and ContentProvider), the subclass is declared through a name attribute. The name must include the full package designation. For example, a Service subclass might be declared as follows:

```
<manifest . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name="com.example.project.SecretService" . . . >
        . . .
    </service>
    . . .
</application>
```

> However, if the first character of the string is a period, the application's package name (as specified by the  element's package attribute) is appended to the string.

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
<application . . . >
    <service android:name=".SecretService" . . . >
        . . .
    </service>
    . . .
</application>
```

My guess would be that your Manifest package is not `arrowsys.vrp.print`, so you'll have to use `<service android:name="arrowsys.vrp.print.service.PrinterService">`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated my manifest XML. it is arrowsys.vrp.print.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<service android:name="arrowsys.vrp.print.service.PrinterService">
```